# halting proof of binary search

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

```
l = -1; u = n;
while l+1 != u
    m = l + (u-l)/2;
    if x[m] < t
        l = m;
    else
        u = m;
p = u;
if p >= n || x[p] != t
     p = -1;
```

We assume x[-1] < t and x[n] >= t and n >= 0 in the above code.
The above code is a modified binary search which can return the *first* occurrence of the integer *t* in the integer array x[0..n-1] instead of returning a random one.

My question is like this:

Why do the above code always halt? Can anyone explain it or prove it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because on every iteration, the gap between `l` and `u` halves, within the constraints of integer arithmetic.  All sequences of (positive) integer halving must eventually reach 1, which is the termination condition.